# Is it possible to use spring security autoconfig with all methods secured and exclude some methods with method security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security

I was wondering is it possible use spring security autoconfig with all methods secured and exclude some methods with method security.

So for example I have one Controller with some methods which are secured per default and I have one method which I want to be public (accessed anonymously).

What I have tried is to do it with `@PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")` but it didn't work because after that, call will be declined and redirected to login in `SecurityFilterChain`.

```
@RestController
public class TestController {
    // ...
    // other secured method

    @GetMapping("/public")
    @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
    @ResponseBody
    public Account secureMethod() {
        return new Account("Name", "Owner");
    }
}
```

So Is there any possibility to achieve this? What I don't want to do is to use Config and exclude this endpoint with `requestMatchers`. I would like to achieve this with method security.

Answer (score 2):

[Method security](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authorization/method-security.html) provides defense in-depth on top of the security filter chain. More specifically, the filter chain is called first so it will always win when it has a more strict authorization rule than a `@PreAuthorize` annotation does.

The default is `anyRequest().authenticated()`, so that explains why you are seeing a login screen (access is denied, and the default `AuthenticationEntryPoint` is executed).

> What I don't want to do is to use Config and exclude this endpoint with `requestMatchers`.

Given your requirements, it does not appear possible, unless you would consider simply specifying a config that includes `anyRequest().permitAll()` and using only `@PreAuthorize` annotations. The problem there is that you have to remember to specify an authorization rule via annotations on **every** endpoint or it will be public. I would generally **not recommend** this.

Comment: Yes, the only way how I managed to do it is to permitAll() all requests and to anotate methods which need authorisation rule, but as you said, it is dangerous if yoi forget it. But I thought maybe there is a construct  which overrides FilterChain rules and can be used in order to exclude default authentication. But thanks for your answer. @Steve Riesenberg